# Python: convert list to generator

Tags: python

Say I have a list

```
data = []
data.append("A")
data.append("B")
data.append("C")
data.append("D")
```

How do I convert this to a generator?
Any help with sample code would be highly appreciated...

Found a URL: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/04/05/implementing-a-generatoryield-in-a-python-c-extension/

Is this what I want to do?

Answer (score 73):

Are you sure, you want to create a *generator*? A generator is function which returns an iterator type, constructed e.g. by using the `yield` keyword (cf. [term-generator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator)).
If you really want this, [steven-rumbalski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322401/steven-rumbalski)'s answer is precisely what you are looking for:

```
data_gen = (y for y in data)
```

Most of the time, you will want to directly create an [*iterator*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) object, e.g. to use the `next()` method. In this case, the answer is implicit in the comment by [mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) above:

```
data_iter = iter(data)
```

which is equivalent to `data_iter = data.__iter__()`, cf. [functions#iter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter).

Answer (score 44):

```
>>> (n for n in [1, 2, 3, 5])
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x02A52940>
```

works in Python 2.7.4+

```
>>> a2g = lambda x : (n for n in x)
>>> a2g([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x02A57CD8>
```

Edit:

One more slight variation of a lambda generator factory pattern

```
>>> a2g = lambda *args: (n for n in args)
>>> for i in a2g(1, 2, 3, 4, 5): print i

1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 7):

The literal equivalent would be:

```
def data_generator():
    yield 'A'
    yield 'B'
    yield 'C'
    yield 'D'
```

Calling the generator function returns a generator-iterator.  Passing the generator-iterator to the list constructor gives:

```
>>> list(data_generator())
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

This generator-iterator can also be created using a generator expression:

```
data_iter = (c for c in 'ABCD')
```

**Note:**  You filled your list with four append statements.  That's typically not how you would write it.

Rather do:

```
data = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import itertools
iter_data = itertools.chain(data)
```

like so:

```
In [10]: data
Out[10]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [11]: iter_data=itertools.chain(data)

In [12]: iter_data
Out[12]: <itertools.chain at 0x1ce8950>

In [13]: iter_data.next()
Out[13]: 1
```

Comment: FWIW, this isn't any different than `iter_data = iter(data)` ... You're not actually chaining anything here.

Comment: not chaining anything? one can't have a single link chain? ;-)

Comment: @CameronSparr No. No you can't ._.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a generator function:

```
def gen():
    for x in "ABCD":
        yield x

In [9]: it = gen()

In [10]: next(it)
Out[10]: 'A'

In [11]: next(it)
Out[11]: 'B'

In [12]: next(it)
Out[12]: 'C'

In [13]: next(it)
Out[13]: 'D'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> 
>>> def gen(d):
...     for i in d:
...             yield i
... 
>>> for i in gen(d):
...     print i
... 
A
B
C
D
>>>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change this to a closure? Put your def inside a function that has the list at the same level as the def then return the generator with list included?

Comment: @MarkKortink You can: `gen = lambda d: (i for i in d)`. On the other hand, this is super unreadable and I would advice against using it anywhere in productive code.

Answer (score 1):

```
(item for item in listNameHere).next()
```

This is the general way of doing it, if I recall correctly.

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> x = (item for item in a)
>>> x
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x028B8440>
>>> x.next()
0
>>> x.next()
1
>>> x.next()
2
```

etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21622696/2936673

> In 3.x, there is no longer a `.next` method attached to these; instead, use the built-in free function `next`:

So to make and step through generator or iterator:

```py
> list_iterator = (d for d in data)  # or list_iterator = iter(data)
> next(list_iterator)
'A'
```